# Indy IMAP - which property to use for identifying new email messages?

Tags: delphi, imap, indy

Using: Delphi XE2, latest Indy snapshot from SVN (10.6.0.4997)

In the case of IMAP there are 2 properties - UID and MsgID which can be used to uniquely identify a message in a mailbox.

1. I'm writing an email client, and need to know which is the more reliable or recommended of the two to store everytime the client connects and retrieves the message list.
2. What sequence of steps are needed to check for new emails? I'm specifically looking for the correct sequence and set of Indy IdIMAP4 commands to get new emails.

Comment: MsgID is set by the sending mail server and UID is set by the receiving mail server. So you should use the UID for identification http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike POP3/SMTP, IMAP defines flags on emails.  The `TIdMessage.Flags` property has `mfRecent` and `mfSeen` flags available (amongst others).  Your client can look for emails that have `mfRecent` set on them, then update the flags on the server to clear `mfRecent` and set `mfSeen` as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebau: Which method(s) of IdIMAP4 to use to iterate the messages? I want to avoid using UIDRetrieveAllEnvelopes because it downloads all messages.

Comment: One possibility would be to use `(UID)SearchMailBox()` methods to retrieve the MsgNums of emails that match specified filter criteria. For instance, one criteria allows you to search for messages that have the `Recent` flag set, and another criteria allows you to search for `Unseen` messages.